# How to fix JNI project that does not run

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface, shared-libraries, mingw

I have a simple JNI project, which compiles. But when I run it, I get the following error:

```
$ java HelloJNI
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassFormatError: Extra bytes at the end of class file HelloJNI
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
```

I had to change a lot of things. On Ubuntu using gcc; it works:

```
ghostrider@:~/programing/java/jni/HelloJNI$ java -Djava.library.path=. HelloWorld
Hello from C!
ghostrider@:~/programing/java/jni/HelloJNI$ ls
ctest.c  HelloWorld.class  HelloWorld.h  HelloWorld.java  libctest.so
```

I used this [link](http://stuf.ro/calling-c-code-from-java-using-jni) to get it working.

So my question now is can I use gcc to compile for a Windows architecture or do I have to install MinGw to do that? 
Thanks for everyone's help.

I just validated that this works with MinGw-64

```
C:\Users\sansari\Downloads\x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc-4.8.0-win64_rubenvb\mingw64\java>gcc -o ctest.dll -shared -I"%JAVA_HOME%\include" -I"%JAVA_HOME%\include\win32" ctest.c -m64

C:\Users\sansari\Downloads\x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc-4.8.0-win64_rubenvb\mingw64\java>ls
HelloWorld.class  HelloWorld.h  HelloWorld.java  ctest.c  ctest.dll

C:\Users\sansari\Downloads\x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc-4.8.0-win64_rubenvb\mingw64\java>java HelloWorld
Hello from C!
```

Comment: Which options are you using for `javac`? Does the `java` version match the VM that you're targeting when you compile?

Comment: I simply used javac HelloJNI.java, and yes the VM and java should match. I am doing this on a laptop, which did not have java. I just installed JDK and used MinGw to compile the c portion.

Comment: To your new question. You can use any compiler which is able to produce Windows binaries. MinGW is a [port of the GNU Compiler Collection (GCC), including C, C++, ADA and Fortran compilers](http://mingw.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you did something wrong as the classloader complains about a broken class.

Following steps are needed in general (you have not told us which one you did)

```
javac HelloJNI.java
javah -jni HelloJNI
# compile your HelloJNI.cpp
```

Fix the library name in your Java class

```
instead of  : System.loadLibrary("hello");
it should be: System.loadLibrary("HelloJNI");
```

Following steps produce a valid DLL on CentOS 7 (sorry no MinGW for Windows at hand)

```
javac HelloJNI.java
javah HelloJNI
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -Wl,-kill-at -Wall -O0 -o HelloJNI.dll -shared \
   -I. -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-openjdk/include \
   -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-openjdk  /include/linux HelloJNI.cpp
```

Copy the `HelloJNI.class` and `HelloJNI.dll` into the same directory on a 64bit Windows machine.

```
java HelloJNI
```

output

```
Hello World!
```

Comment: @Suboptimal- Well I changed the library name, and compiled again. I think I need some help with the java library path. Please note the output in the main part of the post.

Comment: I think I may have found the issue. My machine is a 64 bit machine, and the version of java I installed is 64 bit also. Should I perhaps specify that I want a 64-bit dll file when I use gcc? I used gcc for other c compilations, and I was able to execute the program.

Comment: @user3326293 The shared library called by the JVM has to have the same architecture. You cannot mix 64bit and 32bit. So you need to specify that you want a 64bit DLL.

Comment: @SubOptimal- You d'man! Dude, you have helped so much. Change your username to superman I would say.

Comment: @user3326293 Glad to hear that your problem could be solved.